# ServiceStack IReturn

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I am looking at the new api that came out 2 weeks ago. It seems like

```
ReqDTO : IReturn<List<ResDTO>> { //... }
```

The "IReturn" bit seems to be optional? The DTOs in RazorRockstars demo project works without it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a new addition in [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) which allows you to document the expected Response Type that the Request DTO will return, e.g. with

```
ReqDTO : IReturn<List<ResDTO>> { ... }
```

Which lets you call using any of the C# Service Clients with:

```
List<ResDTO> response = client.Get(new ReqDto());
```

If you didn't have the IReturn marker your client call would have to look like:

```
List<ResDTO> response = client.Get<List<ResDTO>>(new ReqDto());
```

Which is something the client/consumer of your service needs to know about. If you had the marker on the DTO the response type is already known.

The `IReturn<>` marker is also used to determine the Response DTO that's used in the HTTP Responses in ServiceStack's `/metadata` pages.

Comment: Using ServiceStack 3.9.x and I'm just wondering if the `IReturn` is enforced at all? i.e. if my endpoint returns data that does not match the type specified, should it throw exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is just a convenient way of defining your request/response DTOs.
You're free to use it, or not.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you define your DTOs in a portable class library, you won't be able to use IReturn. Perhaps IReturn should be defined in a PCL in ServiceStack. Just a thought.